# Can't import firebase auth after export firebase.auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

after I initialize firebase in firebase.js, I can't import it in App.js, "Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase' in 'G:\React\Projekty\Reactflix\src\services'". I've installed firebase in version "^9.0.2".

Here is firebase.js:

```js
    import firebase from 'firebase';   
    
    //firebase Config
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
      authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
      databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL,
      projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
      storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
      messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
      appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID,
    };
    
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    export const auth = firebase.auth;
```

And my App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
    
    import Home from './pages/Home';
    import Movies from './pages/Movies';
    import Series from './pages/Series';
    import MyList from './pages/MyList';
    import Signup from './pages/Signup';
    import Login from './pages/Login';
    import Page404 from './pages/Page404';
    import Profile from './pages/Profile';
    import { auth } from './services/firebase'
    
    import './App.css';
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          Reactflix
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Finally error message:
[firebase_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tv5U1.png)

Is something wrong with the code? Looks good for me...

Answer (score 0):

The `firebase` npm package [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) says to import it like:

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
```